# How to execute or run xyz.py file from app.py file on button click in python flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am very new to python and Flask. I need to run two `xyz.py` and `abc.py` files within `app.py` on button click using python flask.

`app.py`:

```py
@app.route("/")
def home():  
    return render_template('home.html')
```

`home.html`:

```html
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="toggle_display()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Now here I need to run `xyz.py` and `abc.py` files on "Button onclick" event. 
Would you please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by arranging your files as follows (run.py == app.py), I have tested it on Flask version 1.1.1

[image]

in run.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from app.abc import TestABC
from app.xyz import TestXYZ

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/after-btn-click")
def home():
    print(TestABC.abc_def())
    print(TestXYZ.xyz_def())
    return render_template('a template')
```

in abc.py file

```
class TestABC:
    @staticmethod
    def abc_def():
        return "ABC file is called"
```

in xyz.py file

```
class TestXYZ:
    @staticmethod
    def xyz_def():
        return "xyz file is called"
```

only task left is to redirect your website after button click or use a ajax request to call the specific url ("/after-btn-click").

hopefully this will help you in achieving your goal

Comment: thank you Amit, i did the same with little changes in the code.